# Is it possible to cancel asynchronous call independently of its current state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, throttling, cancellation

When I type text into my textfield widget I send request with every character typed into it to get matching data from the server.

When I type really fast I swarm server with the requests and this causes to freeze my control, I managed to create throttling mechanism where I set how many ms client should wait before sending request. This requires to set arbitrary constant ms to wait. The better solution would be to just cancel sending previous request when the next key button is pressed.

Is it possible to cancel AJAX request independently of its current state? If yes, how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean, "independent of its current state"? No, you cannot cancel a request that already has succeeded.

Comment: Why are your controls freezing? Too many requests? Synchronous requests? In either case, throttling the requests ("waiting") is the only solution, cancelling will not really help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Call `XMLHttpRequest.abort()`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

You'll have to track your requests somehow, perhaps in an array.

```
requests = [];

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/";

requests.push(xhr);
```

Answer (score 0):

[MDN says :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort)

> The XMLHttpRequest.abort() method aborts the request if it has already
>   been sent. When a request is aborted, its readyState is set to 0
>   (UNSENT), but the readystatechange event is not fired.

What's important to note here is that while you will be able to `.abort()` requests on the client side (and thus not have to worry about the server's response), you are still swarming your server because all those requests are still being sent.

My opinion is that you had it right the first time, by implementing a mechanism that limits the frequency of AJAX requests. You mentioned that you had a problem with this freezing your control (I assume you mean that the browser is either taking longer to respond to user actions, or stops responding completely), and this could be a sign that there is a problem with the way your application handles asynchronous code.

Make sure you are using async APIs like `Promise` correctly, avoid loops that do heavy processing or just wait around in client code, and make your event processing (i.e your AJAX callback) simple and fast to reduce the impact on the user.